# MongoDB, push new value to array without duplicating the key

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm kinda beginner with `MongoDB` and got task to push new values to Database, but only values to make it as a array, the thing is that current query duplicate everything, value and key, here is example:

```
"battery_message" : [
                {
                        "ChargerState" : null
                },
                {
                        "ChargerStatus" : null
                },
                {
                        "OutputVoltage" : null
                },
                {
                        "timestamp" : 1561442271.976242
                },
                {
                        "ChargerState" : null
                },
                {
                        "ChargerStatus" : null
                },
                {
                        "OutputVoltage" : null
                },
                {
                        "timestamp" : 1561442302.637065
                }
        ],
```

The thing is that probably some new date might appear in battery message so in my schema it looks like this:

```
battery_message: Array
```

And here is my query:

```
deviceControllers.updateDevice(
            {device_id: message.device_id},
            {$push: { battery_message: [
                {ChargerState: message.data.ChargerState},
                {ChargerStatus: message.data.ChargerStatus},
                {OutputVoltage: message.data.OutputVoltage},
                {timestamp: message.data.timestamp},
            ]}}
        )
```

Basically the idea is to make later for example ChargerState: `[value, value, value, etc.]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html#addtoset-aggregation) with [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/index.html#each) to update the existing array. Here `$addToSet` operator `adds` or `appends` a value to an array, only if the value does not exist in the array.

So, your query might look something like:

```
deviceControllers.updateDevice(
        {device_id: message.device_id},
        {$addToSet: { battery_message:
        {
            $each: [
                   message.data.ChargerState,
                   message.data.ChargerStatus,
                   message.data.OutputVoltage,
                   message.data.timestamp
            ]
        }}})
```

> **Update 1** if `battery_message` have properties as :`ChargerState:Array,ChargerStatus:Array,OutputVoltage:Array,timeStamp:Array`

```
deviceControllers.updateDevice(
{device_id: message.device_id},
{$addToSet: { 
    battery_message.ChargerState:{$each:[value1,value2,,,,]},
    battery_message.ChargerStatus:{$each:[value1,value2,,,,]},
    battery_message.OutputVoltage:{$each:[value1,value2,,,,]},
    battery_message.timestamp:{$each:[value1,value2,,,,]}
}
})
```

Here if the key(s) ex:`battery_message.ChargerState` does not exist it will be created.

**Note:**

- Just make sure that the key `battery_message` is an `object` and not an `array` and if the key(s) are meant to be separate individual key instead of nested-key please remove the `battery_message` key from the command.
- If only a single entry has to be appended to an array than your query would look something like: `$addToSet:{battery_message.ChargerState: message.data.ChargerState}`

Comment: Works well my friend but the thing is that it put only values now, later it will be hard to distinguish which value belongs to what property, so i wanted to have each Charger stuff as a separate array, that way data would land in array it belongs to. is it possible to make it done without changing Schema? Or to achieve that i would need to change schema to  `battery_message: { ChargerState: Array, ChargerStatus: Array}` etc.? EDIT, turned out it doesn't work well as now it is stored in one array, so it means that state status and voltage and mixing with each other, not kept in separate fields

Comment: @Zirek, in that case, the `$addToSet` will have multiple objects with their respective values in each statement. anyway, i have updated my answer.

Comment: it works perfectly fine now! thank you so much for your help:) only it is not `battery_message.ChargerState:{$each:[value1,value2,,,,]}` but needs to be with quotes otherwise it gives error, `"battery_message.ChargerState":{$each:[value1,value2,,,,]}` :)

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, if the path to the key is defined, have to use a string instead.